# Invalid Escape Character

Tags: java

Making a server in java,
First off, Here's the code.

```
    AnsiConsole.out.println("This is a Test.");
    AnsiConsole.out.println("\e[0;31m Red");
    AnsiConsole.out.println("\e[0;34m Blue");
    AnsiConsole.out.println("\e[0;32m Green");
    AnsiConsole.out.println("\e[1;33m Yellow");
```

So, my issue is that it reads the escape characters as illegal.
Any Comments?

Using the Jansi Library http://jansi.fusesource.org/index.html

Comment: Perhaps you want `\u001b` which is the ESC character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're trying to produce [ANSI Escape Sequences](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php) here.

`\e` is not a valid character in Java, what you need is instead `\u001b` which is the start of the ANSI sequence.

```
AnsiConsole.out.println("\u001b[0;31m Red");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the backslash:

```
AnsiConsole.out.println("This is a Test.");
AnsiConsole.out.println("\\e[0;31m Red");
AnsiConsole.out.println("\\e[0;34m Blue");
AnsiConsole.out.println("\\e[0;32m Green");
AnsiConsole.out.println("\\e[1;33m Yellow");
```

Because in Java, the backslash `\` has [a special meaning](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) in strings: it's used for special characters such as `\n` (new line) or `\t`  (tab).

There's a good description of the topic [here](http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Escape_sequences_and_escape_characters#Java).

Answer (score 1):

It's because `\e` is not a valid escape sequence. If you do want to print the backslash, you need to escape it: `"\\e[0;31m Red"`

You can check [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) for a list of valid escape sequences.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include a '\' (backslash) in the printed string you should escape it with another '\' => `AnsiConsole.out.println("\\e[0;31m Red");`

Currently java understands you try to escape 'e' which is not a special character and it complains about that.